# Why is nums[3:-1:-1] empty instead of the first 4 elements of nums in reverse? Python list slice with positive start, -1 stop, and -1 step

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

Say I have a list called `nums` and I want to get a reversed, prefix of `nums` - i.e. the first `start` elements of `nums` in reverse order. **Assuming `0 <= start <= n` where `n = len(nums)`**, the following work

###### Get prefix, then reverse:

- `nums[:start][::-1]` is a list
- `reversed(nums[:start])` is a reverse iterator, not a list
- `list(reversed(nums[:start]))` is a list

###### Reverse, then get suffix:

- `nums[::-1][-start:] if start else []` is a list
- `list(reversed(nums))[-start:] if start else []` is a list

###### Using comprehension:

- `[nums[i] for i in range(start-1, -1, -1)]`

Each slice or `list(.)` call creates a new list and each `reversed(.)` call adds overhead, so ideally there's a way to do this using just one slice and nothing else. There is

###### One slice working approaches (still assuming 0 <= start <= n):

- `nums[-(n+1-start): -(n+1): -1]`
- `nums[  start-1:    -(n+1): -1] if start else []`

but they're confusing. I would have thought the following one slice approaches would have also worked, but they didn't:

###### One slice (non-working approaches):

- `nums[start-1: -1: -1] if start else []`
- `nums[-(n+1-start): -1: -1]`

I find it confusing that `nums[start-1: -1: -1]` does not work given that it breaks the following pattern (assuming `start = 4 <= n = len(nums)`):

- `nums[3: 3:-1]` is `[]`
- `nums[3: 2:-1]` is `[nums[3]]`
- `nums[3: 1:-1]` is `[nums[3], nums[2]]`
- `nums[3: 0:-1]` is `[nums[3], nums[2], nums[1]]`
- `nums[3:-1:-1]` is `[]` *(breaks the pattern)*

following the pattern above, one would expect `nums[3:-1:-1]` to be `[nums[3], nums[2], nums[1], nums[0]]`, but instead it is `[]`. Why?

The only thing that comes to mind is that a `stop` of `-1` is treated as a `stop` of `len(nums)-1`.

Comment: You want to use `nums[3::-1]` to do this.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because the index `-1` is treated as `len(nums)-1`.

Comment: You can also use `nums[3:None:-1]` if you need to store *end* in a variable, e.g. `start, end, step = 3, None, -1`.

Comment: A stop of `-1` as is equivalent to `len(nums) - 1`